# get email account url from a .aspx page by Request.UrlReferrer. in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a "registration user" `.aspx` page.
i want send this page link to an email account and user forced click on this link to going this page.
i using `"Request.UrlReferrer"` to get the email account `url` for my `.aspx` page to validate users but `"Request.UrlReferrer"` can not return email account `url` and its value is null
my page load code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    string previousPageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

string thisPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
if (previousPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() || thisPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
   {
     my coads
   }
}
```

but :

```
string previousPageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

has exception

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer might be null.

Comment: i want get foreign page url by `string previousPageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Webmail is accessed through HTTPS, which hides the referrer, and I don't think the user's mail address is in the webmail URL anyway (https://www.gmail.com/inbox/mailid for example).

Just use an identifier in the URL you send in the mail, so when clicked, you can relate the link to a user on your site.

Comment: but... how i can understand user register own by valid email address or no??

Comment: @MohammadReza there are other ways to do this approach, e.g. sending a random code as a `QueryString` after registering, etc..

Comment: i know understand correctly?  i must send random string to user email and cheked if the string is equal to my string value the user validation is valid?

Answer (score 0):

It's preferred to send activation code to user's email after registering e.g.
You should have a column in your user table as `ActivationCode` to get more details go [Here](http://iranganj.ir/asp/128/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B3-%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84-%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%86%DA%A9-%D9%81%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-asp-net).

But based on your question:

1- You can not access to `previousPageUrl` because it defined in first if block

2- You will got null `Exception` if you opened browser without pressing a link to get there.

Try this:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                string previousPageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                string thisPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
                if (previousPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() || thisPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
                {
                }
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                //Log exception
            }
        }
```

Or this is better:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                string previousPageUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                string thisPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
                if (previousPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() || thisPageUrl == Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i think `Request.Url` & `Request.UrlReferrer` can get my web site pages url and can not get Foreign url pages

Comment: No you can test it in your localhost by two project like a piece of cake.

Comment: @MohammadReza To confirm registered user take a look at [here](http://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?409931-%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%AF-%D9%81%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA-%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87) as an Iranian forum.

Comment: @MohammadReza Have you got your answer?

Comment: Pretty much... but i have test this ways to do is Efficient or no for my project

Comment: @MohammadReza I think this is efficient because you forced user to open another page to be active, but your code always check `UrlReferrer`, maybe there are a lot of  link to your page. anyway if you think this is your solution plz `accept` it.